# SQL joining a large amount of tables and comparing queries to return a specific result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I am working with a database that was handed down to me. It has approximately 25 tables, and a very buggy query system that hasn't worked correctly for a while. I figured, instead of trying to bug test the existing code, I'd just start over from scratch. I want to say before I get into it, "I'm not asking anyone to build the code for me". I'm not that lazy, all I want to know is, what would be the best way to lay out the code? The existing query uses "JOIN" to combine the results of all the tables in one variable, and spits it into the query. I have been told in other questions displaying this code, that it's just too much, and far too many bugs to try to single out what is causing the break.

What would be the most efficient way to query these tables that reference each other?

Example: Person chooses car year, make, model. PHP then gathers that information, and queries the SQL database to find what parts have matching year, vehicle id's, and parts compatible. It then uses those results to pull parts that have matching car model id's, OR vehicle id's(because the database was built very sloppily, and compares all the different tables to produce: Parts, descriptions, prices, part number, sku number, any retailer notes, wheelbase, drive-train compatibility, etc.

I've been working on this for two weeks, and I'm approaching my deadline with little to no progress. I'm about to scrap their database, and just do data entry for a week, and rebuild their mess if it would be easier, but if I can use the existing pile of crap they've given me, and save some time, I would prefer it.

Would it be easier to do a couple queries and compare the results, then use those results to query for more results, and do it step by step like that, or is one huge query comparing everything at once more efficient?

Should I use JOIN and pull all the tables at once and compare, or pass the input into individual variables, and pass the PHP into javascript on the client side to save server load? Would it be simpler to break the code up so I can identify the breaking points, or would using one long string decrease query time, and server loads? This is a very complex question, but I just want to make sure there aren't too many responses asking for clarification on trivial areas. I'm mainly seeking the best advice possible on how to handle this complicated situation.

Comment: A JOIN is the standard way t connect the data between two or mor etables

Comment: I see that JOIN is very useful in this situation, but can it be utilized efficiently to JOIN and compare multiple values across multiple tables with indexes that cross reference other associated columns from that row in 24 other tables without a cms? It seems a bit excessive for something that should be simpler. I can see how the setup could be beneficial, but the way it is, makes it so when one item is added the the inventory, all 25 tables need updating. That just seems ludacris to me.

Comment: Maybe their syntax was just wrong. Could anyone give me a good generic example of code relating this way? Get yearID,match with yearID from modelyear table, then match yearID = to VID from model table, then match modelID with IdModel from make table? That's just the beginning. If I can get that comparison working though, I can probably get the whole query to work with enough effort.

Answer (score -1):

Rebuild the database then make a php import to bring over the data.